# Is there a way to open ios shortcuts app from flutter app?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I have used  [flutter_siri_suggestions](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_siri_suggestions)  package to to add a user activity.

after I add the activity I can add shortcut in the shortcut app to siri.

But I want to add the shortcut programmatically, when click 'Hey Siri, open my app' button I want to open the shortcut app and fill the when I say: and Do: field to be filled with data from the flutter app.

I tried to find a way but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Is there a any way to open the shortcuts app from flutter programmatically and add a shortcut to siri?[flutter_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBr9H.png) and [shortcuts_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTepr.jpg)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/siri_shortcuts